# Recursively modifying an object with Promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, recursion, promise

I'm trying to traverse through results from ElasticSearch and modify the original object by replacing items in an array. I am almost through, but the Promise is resolved more than once, leaving me with no usable result.

I'm using `source.included = Array.map()` to replace the original array with the results of the function call and it works *almost*. It's important to keep the original structure of the object and the order within the `included` array, that's why I decided to try this approach. I tried to orient myself on [this example](http://www.2ality.com/2016/04/promise-trees.html), but Promise.all() somehow won't resolve the promises. Any ideas?

```
let source = {
  title: '1',
  included: [{
    _id: 'new',
    _type: 'mytype'
  }]
}

function recursiveGet (source) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    client.mget({
      body: {
        docs: docsToFetch
      }
    })
    .then(response => {
      return source.included.map(item => {
        return somethingAsync(response)
      })
    })
    .then(promises => {
      Promise.all(promises)
        .then(resolved => {
          source.included = resolved.map(doc => {
            if (doc.included && !doc.resolved) {
              resolve(recursiveGet(doc))
            } else {
              resolve(doc)
            }
          })
        })
    })
  })
}

recursiveGet(source)
```

Comment: *"but the Promise is resolved more than once"* No, it isn't. Promises by definition are only resolved (technically, *settled*) once.

Comment: I only have done this with $q in Angular. The trick was to pass the deferred object (the promise) to your recursive function.

Comment: Please provide **exact input, required output and specific problem**.

Comment: _"but Promise.all() somehow won't resolve the promises."_ What do you mean? You do not `return` `Promise.all()` from last `.then()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572)!

You cannot (must not) call the `resolve` multiple times - in your case, from within a `map` loop. Use this instead:

```
function recursiveGet (source) {
  return client.mget({
    body: {
      docs: docsToFetch
    }
  }).then(response => {
    let promises = source.included.map(item => {
      return somethingAsync(response) // did you mean `item` here?
    })
    return Promise.all(promises);
  })
  .then(resolved => {
    let morePromises = resolved.map(doc => {
//                              ^^^ another loop...
      if (doc.included && !doc.resolved) {
        return recursiveGet(doc);
      } else {
        return doc;
      }
    });
    return Promise.all(morePromises).then(moreResults => {
//         ^^^^^^^^^^^ another Promise.all!
      source.included = moreResults;
      return source;
    });
  });
}
```

If you don't want two sequential loops, you can also chain each of the result processing callbacks to the `somethingAsync` promise directly.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks! Needed a resolve() in the last .then() and therefore keep the anti-pattern, but it works.

Comment: @Patrick: No, you absolutely should not keep the antipattern.

Comment: I've tried a couple of ways to remove it, but if there's no resolve() in the final then(), the Promise won't resolve.

Comment: @Patrick: You should completely omit the `new Promise` call, and `return` the return value of the final `then()` call. There is no need to call `resolve` when there is no `resolve` callback around. Have a closer look at the begin of the code in my answer again.

Comment: That's what I did .. Return the client.mget and return source in the final then, still, the Promise doesn't get back to the main code. I'll go through and try a few more things, but it's a great start to have it working. Was becoming desperate with this.